# CSS only working on first load of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I created a JSP within the content area of a SAP Portal. This JSP contains Javascript and CSS that manipulates the content of an iframe within this content area. The Javascript is always excecuting perfecly. The CSS is only working if internet explorer and the page is opened for the first time. How is this possible? Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Can we have a little of your code to eat ? Please.

Comment: What do you mean by _opened for the first time_?

Comment: make sure that the references to the css files are not relative. Moving to different pages and frames in a tree like file system on the host, and it can't be found anymore.

Comment: If I initially open IE and navigate to the page in the SAP Portal the CSS works. The page contains my custom JSP component and another iframe with content that I am modifying via javascript and css in my JSP component. The navigation occurs withon the iframe that contains the content I am modifying.